# Golang postgres driver panics when using transactions

Tags: postgresql, go

So... this was apperantly an issue a few years ago, atleast there are several bugs with what I **think** is the same issue. In a method I have 2 transactions, one after the other (so they are not concurrent, they are sequencial) and the second transaction always fails.

This is roughly the code:

```
import (
        "database/sql"
        _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)
var db *sql.DB

func InitStorage() {
        var err error
        db, err = sql.Open(os.Getenv("DB_CONNECTION_DRIVER"), os.Getenv("DB_CONNECTION_STRING"))
        if err != nil {
                glog.Error(err)
        }   
        if db == nil {
                glog.Fatal(db)
        }   
        tx, err := db.Begin()
   if err != nil {
            glog.Error(err)
        } else {
            glog.Info("ERROR ON BEGIN IS NiLL!!!")
        }   

        _, err = tx.Query(`INSERT INTO urls(url_hash, url) VALUES($1, $2)`, `asdadsaaa`, `1313`)
        if err != nil {
                glog.Error(err)
                tx.Rollback()
        }   
        tx.Commit()
        glog.Info("SECOND TRANSACTION!!!")
        tx1, err := db.Begin()
   if err != nil {
            glog.Error("SECOND TRANSACTION HAS ERR: ", err)
        } else {
            glog.Info("ERROR ON BEGIN IS NiLL!!!")
        }   
        _, err = tx1.Query(`INSERT INTO urls(url_hash, url) VALUES($1, $2)`, `asdadsaaa`, `1313`)
        if err != nil {   
                glog.Error(err)
                tx1.Rollback()
        }   
        tx1.Commit()
}
```

And this is always the output (I have cut the end, since it doesn't bring useful information):

```
I0324 00:24:26.192256   11580 storage_rdb.go:33] ERROR ON BEGIN IS NiLL!!!
I0324 00:24:26.195134   11580 storage_rdb.go:42] SECOND TRANSACTION!!!
E0324 00:24:26.195197   11580 storage_rdb.go:45] SECOND TRANSACTION HAS ERRpq: unexpected transaction status idle in transaction
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x5460cb]

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x7c41c0, 0xc820010150)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x3e6
database/sql.(*Tx).Query(0x0, 0x8b2e00, 0x2e, 0xc82011fd50, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc82001a540, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1404 +0x3b
main.InitStorage()
```

I assume I am doing something wrong(since the bug was found in 2013), but I can't figure out what it is. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an error on the first commit?

Comment: You're doing a tx.Query for an INSERT. You should use tx.Exec. Query expects to return rows.

Comment: nah for postgres drivers the query just returns the inserted row so I don't think that's it. This begs 2 questions. Does the connection have the ability to select? Does the error resolve if you clean up the returned rows explicitly by closing the cursor on the return value? I'm pretty much shooting in the dark here, this error is pretty.. well not nice haha